# Tomcat 9.027: port out of range

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets

I have a problem with connect my servlet with Tomcat v9.0.27.
When I try start my servlet in IntelliJ, Tomcat give me this error:

> Error running 'Tomcat 9.0.27': port out of range:-1

My port is 8080, I try to change port but this not help me
Windows 10, x64

My configuration from IntellJ:
https://zapodaj.net/3eab70769b2ef.png.html

My code:

```
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet("/hello")
public class hello extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
        writer.println("HelloWorld");
    }
}
```

Anybody have any solution to this problem?

Comment: "My port is 8080" - It seems like your port is actually `-1`. Where do you set it to `8080`? Can you send your code?

Comment: https://zapodaj.net/3eab70769b2ef.png.html @JacobG. this is my full configuration from IntellJ IDEA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have a solution, we need to go to the configuration files of our Tomcat:

> C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat/conf

We must edit our server.xml.

In line:

> Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"

you must change "-1" to something else but greater than zero, for example:

> Server port="1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"

Then only save all changes, and restart your project.

Have a nice day!

Comment: You must change "-1" to the actual port you want the server listening to.

Comment: It's true, but have you another different solution which work ?